# blackberry replaced field is shifted to right and buttom

Tags: blackberry

In `GridFieldManager` or in Main Screen when i try to replace one field with another, (in particular existing `LabelField` for example), the another field is shifted to right and bottom by 3-5 pix. In a 10-iteration loop this shift is very visible.

What is this ?

Comment: If GridFieldManager have 2 rows,  shift is only buttom
If GridFieldManager have 1 row shift to right and buttom by 4 pix.
So as MainScreen  have "1 row", shift  is ight and buttom

Comment: Can you please log this as an issue to BlackBerry Developer Tracker. Sample code would also be helpful. https://www.blackberry.com/jira/secure/Dashboard.jspa